# How to generate MIDI file with single track using MIDIUtil

Tags: python, midi

I am trying to generate `MIDI` files that are type 0 single track with all messages saved in one track. The `Python` package I used is `MIDIUtil`.

Here is the post I was following the post [How can I write a MIDI file with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059801/how-can-i-write-a-midi-file-with-python).

However, based on the document of `MIDIUtil`. It supports `"format 1 (the default) and format 2 files"`, but not type `0`?

Here is the link the the file format documentation, http://midiutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creating.html#
file-format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to its documentation, that library indeed does not support format 0 files.

However, it never checks the `file_format` parameter, so you can simply use `file_format = 0`, and ensure that all events (including timing events) are put into a single track.
(If this works, file a bug to update the documentation.)

Comment: It worked with `file_format=0`. I opened an issue. Thank you for the help!